# Указатели, массивы и структуры

Tags: c

Для следующего фрагмента программы записать в виде таблицы значение переменных после каждого шага программы (столбцы соответствуют переменным, строки – строкам программы). Тип int и указатели занимают по 4 байта. Компилятор расположил переменные по следующим адресам: a – 100, p1 – 120,  p2 – 124, s.x – 128, s.y – 132. Число N – номер варианта.

```
struct str {int x; int y;}; 
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
int *p1, *p2; 
str s; 
p1 = &a[N%5+1]; //первая строка таблицы
p2 = a+N/5+1;   //2-я строка
s.x = *p1;      //3-я строка
s.y = *p2++;    //4-я строка
*(p1-2)=s.y;    //5-я строка
p2=&s;          //6-я строка
p2->x=p1[1];    //7-я строка
p2–>y=s.y;      //8-я строка
a[5]=s.x;       //9-я строка
```

Таблица, как я понял, должна быть из 5 столбцов и 9 строк со значениями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как-то так? Только вот в 8-й строке не понял - идет присвоение значения самому себе? Поскольку p2 ссылается на s.

Добавлено! Ах, да, N=2.

---

[image: Таблица с вычислениями]

Нашел и исправил недочеты, вот примерно все приведено в таблице. Не совсем понятна строка 7 - указатель ведь на элемент массива? либо же он указывает на элемент с индексом 1 массива (как я в таблице и оформил).
Преподаватель сказал, что в коде есть ошибки, которые нужно исправить, помимо неверного объявления структуры s мб тут тоже ошибка? еще не нравится строка 8 - так можно объявлять? 
Ну и в целом не уверен, что заполнил все верно. Интересует строка 2.

Comment: Да, 8-ая строка ничего не делает.

Comment: Поскольку это явно учебное задание, почему бы вам не спросить у вашего лектора?

Answer (score 3):

По стандарту, обращение к невыделенной памяти есть undefined behaviour. Поэтому код `p1 = &a[N%5+1]; ... *p1` для случая `N = 4` неверен. То же касается кода `p2 = a+N/5+1; ... *p2` для случая `N = 20`.

То, по каким адресам компилятор кладёт какую переменную, не не важно. UB есть UB, и компилятор имеет право делать что угодно в случае, когда оно происходит.

Если ваш преподаватель не знает этого, он застрял в мезозое, в котором компиляторы не умели оптимизировать (и не знает стандарт языка). Полагаться на любое поведение при UB нельзя, если только это не гарантирует ваш конкретный компилятор.

Обязательно к вдумчивому прочтению: A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, [part 1](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213), [part 2](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/226), [part 3](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232).

Comment: понял о чем вы, да, нехорошо получается, но это всего лишь универ. А присвоение в последней стоке тоже не очень хорошо?

Comment: @user193688: Точно так же. Причём если процитированнй мною код есть UB лишь при особых значениях `N`, то `a[5]` есть UB в любом случае.